# secure websockets with quarkus

Tags: java, websocket, quarkus

I build a working websocket server with quarkus. Now, I have to switch from insecure websocket connection to websocket over TLS. But I have no idea how to configure this and can't find this topic within the quarkus docs or an appropriate answer in the questions here.

I'm using Quarkus 2.7.1-Final and imported the websocket-lib via maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-websockets</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In my dev environment everything works like intended. But now I have to switch to the cloud environment that uses https. This ends up with the following error on client side (angular):

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://subdomainA-host/params...' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://subdomainB-host/params...'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.

I implemented the server using the annotations:

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws/..."), @OnOpen, @OnClose, @OnError, @OnMessage

The only websocket related configuration within the application.properties is 'quarkus.websocket.max-frame-size'. But I can't find similar keys to secure the websocket connection.

Does anybody has some hints, snippets or documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you behind a reverse proxy (ie nginx)?
Have you tried setting the endpoint to wss://?

Comment: I tried it with wss:// and failed at first. Then I tried a lots of different things found over the web and suddenly it worked. But I had no idea what made the difference. So I reverted the changes step by step and it is still working after all. Very strange, so I could not figure out what my initial problem was. After all it seems that using wss:// was all do to. Very strange.

Comment: Did you find out how to do this? I have a non-secure Quarkus WS endpoint working but can find no example of securing it eg using Keycloak.

Comment: @Murrah: My intent was never to secure the websocket connection via a kind of token or user/password. All I wanted to do was to use wss over ws and this finally worked as described in one of my comments before.